Question to the definition of derivative of Dirac delta function
I was working on Fourier transform and came across something difficult to understand.
To generalize Fourier transform to smooth functions like sin, cos, $t^n$, and exponential functions etc, the book uses the derivative of delta function and says:
Suppose $f(t)$ is smooth on $(-\infty, +\infty)$ and calculate formally:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta^{'} (t-t_0) f(t) dt = \delta (t-t_0) f(t) |_{-\infty}^{+\infty} - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta (t-t_0) f^{'}(t) dt$$
$$= - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta (t-t_0) f^{'}(t) dt = - f^{'} (t_0)$$
I have the question why $\delta (t-t_0) f(t) |_{-\infty}^{+\infty} = 0$. At first I thought that it is because $\delta(-\infty) = \delta(+\infty) = 0$, but we didn't put any restriction to how $f(t)$ behave at infinity.
I also try to understand this by turning to other definition of delta function. I know it can be defined by distribution, but this cannot answer my question as well.
Can anyone help me? Thank you very much!

the support of $f$ is compact (?)

I agree: compact support is the only real way to make this work out.

I thought it should be but the book describe $f$ as "smooth on $(-\infty, +\infty)$", and I am confused about it. @Sine of the Time

As a rule, it is difficult to understand the delta function  because it is not really a function. It is a distribution.

Then how to understand the definition of $\delta^{'} (t)$ from the view of distribution? Is $\int \delta^{'} (t - t_0) f(t) dt = - f^{'} (t_0)$ just a definition or can be derived? @ThomasAndrews

The definition of the derivative of a distribution is defined so that it coincides,with the derivative of the function, when a distribution comes from a function. So it is, essentially, the definition, yes.

In particular. Distributions are usually applied to functions $f$ which go to $0$ as $x\to\pm\infty,$ so when you apply the integral, $f(x)g(x)\vert_{-\infty}^{+\infty}$  is assumed to be zero.

What book is it? You are right to be puzzled: its notation $\delta (t-t_0) f(t) |_{-\infty}^{+\infty}$ makes no sense.

The $\int$ sign and the parenthesis in $\delta(~)$ are misleading. $\delta_a$ is a distribution with compact support, defined by
$$\langle\delta_a,f\rangle=f(a)$$ for any smooth function $f$ (not necessarily vanishing at infinity).
And the derivative of a distribution $T$ is defined by
$$\langle T',f\rangle=-\langle T,f'\rangle.$$
